# ASP.NET CORE LINQ GROUP BY

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have little problem with group by, i want achieve this

```
Nobukti : 001/des/2019
1000
2000
3000
4000
```

in My controller

```
var transaction = await (from a in _context.Transaction group a by a.Nobukti into pg
                                 join b in _context.ChartAccount on pg.FirstOrDefault().Kodeakun
                                 equals b.Kodeakun
                                  select new Transaksi
                                  {   
                                      Nobukti = pg.First().Nobukti,
                                      Kodeakun = pg.FirstOrDefault().Kodeakun + b.Namaakun
                                  }).ToListAsync();
```

In my View

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nobukti)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nobukti)
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        @foreach (var book in item.Nobukti)
            {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kodeakun)
            </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
    </table>
```

Can anyone help me? i dont know which wrong, my controller or my view,
sorry for english

Comment: Tell if there is any compilation error in your code or you want more performance.

Comment: i dont know whats problem, its my view or my controller, if you can suggest me performance, i will take it too

Comment: @DavidBudiman ASP.NET Core is a web framework that has nothing to do with LINQ or database access. LINQ itself is just the query language, not the ORM that reads from a database. That's probably EF Core. Use the *correct* tags and include the versions you use. Both ASP.NET Core and EF Core have changed a lot from one version to the next

Comment: im sorry, my code works but its not view what i want

Comment: @HasanGholamali, can you help me with linq anonymous type?

Comment: @DavidBudiman add the error message to your question and in which line you got the error?